# What if $\operatorname{div}f=0$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Say, we have a function $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^2)$ such that $\operatorname{div}f=0$. According to the divergence theorem the flux through the boundary surface of any solid region equals zero.

So for $f(x,y)=(y^2,x^2)$ the flux through the boundary surface on the picture (sorry for its thickness, please treat it as a line) is zero.

[image: Zero divergence]

The result (if I interpret the theorem correctly) seems to be quite surprising.

It looks like can also get non-zero flux by zero divergence. For example, $$g(x,y)=(-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$$ (see the next picture) has $\operatorname{div}g=0$ yet the flux is clearly negative.

[image: Unbounded]

The function $g$ isn't continuous at $(0,0)$ and therefore not $C^1$.

My first question is: are there any other cases where divergence is zero yet the flux isn't?

The reasons I'm asking is the exercise I came across:

> Compute the surface integral
>   $$\int_{U}F  \cdot dS$$
>   where $F(x,y)=(y^3, z^3, x^3)$ and $U$ is the unit sphere.

I didn't expect the exercise to be doable mentally (by simply noting that $\operatorname{div}F=0$ and concluding the integral is zero) yet $F$ is clearly $C^1$ so the divergence theorem seems to be applicable. My second question is: am I overlooking something in the exercise?

Comment: what is your definition of ${\rm div}\ f$?

Comment: @janmarqz: $\operatorname{div}f= \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+...+\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}$

Comment: For a surface integral, one integrates over a surface. The unit circle is not a surface. Something is off.

Comment: this other definition  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition_of_divergence] doesn't it help?

Comment: @rghthndsd: I cut one dimension thinking it wasn't relevant. Take a took at the edited problem statement.

Comment: With the edits made, your answer is now correct. It may be instructive to try to calculate the integral by definition (without using the divergence theorem). This is the power of the Green/Stokes/Divergence theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divergence theorem is a statement about 3-dimensional vector fields, the 2-dimensional version sometimes being called the normal version of Green's theorem. In your second example, the vector field

$$g(x,y) = \left( -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)$$

is not even defined at the origin, which is why Green's theorem doesn't apply to it. In the final problem though, the vector field $F$ is well-defined (and $C^1$) everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you can apply the divergence theorem, and conclude that the flux is $0$.